# Let $a_n$ be a sequence, let $b_n=(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)*1/n$. Is it possible to assume that if $b_n$ converges, then $(a_n)/n)$ converges to $0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to solve this question and I'm stuck for whatever reason, I'm not really sure how to start facing this problem, so here's what I've been thinking, given that $b_n$ converges, we know that it's bounded, so there exists some number $k$, so that $-k<b_n<k$, plugging in $b_n$ we get that $-nk<a_1+a_2+...+a_n<nk$. I can't really wrap my head about where I need to go from here (not sure I'm even headed in the right direction), would love some feedback/tips. Thanks

Comment: Use $\lim_{n \to \infty} (b_n - b_{n - 1}) = 0$, then manipulate the difference to try and show what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: $$b_n = \frac{n - 1}{n} b_{n - 1} + \frac{a_n}{n} $$

Comment: Thanks! Managed to get to that and prove it successfully!